# How can I filter over multiple data frames in a for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, filter, error-handling

I'm trying to work with [this](https://www.huduser.gov/portal/datasets/ahar/2022-ahar-part-1-pit-estimates-of-homelessness-in-the-us.html) Excel sheet about homelessness point-in-time estimates with R. The Excel workbook I'm using is 2007-2022 Point-in-Time Estimates by CoC. When I run a for loop to filter for rows, I get the error

Error in UseMethod("filter") :
no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "list"

Ultimately, I want to run through the dataframes on the list florida using a for loop.

Here is what I did

```
library(rio) # this is excellent for spreadsheets with multiple sheets
library(tidyverse) # we need this for exploratory data analysis and visualization
```

path <- ""   # file path needed

```
florida <- import_list(path)  #makes large list of dataframes 

florida <- florida[-c(9:17)] # needed ethnicity data only exists for 2015-2022, so drop rows
```

Here is my issue where I encounter the error.

```
names(florida) <- paste0('df', 2015:2022)
list2env(florida, .GlobalEnv)

for (i in 1:length(florida)){
  df[[i]] %>%
    filter( "cocname" == "Gainesville/Alachua, Putnam Counties CoC")
}
```

I want the rows of data over the years specific to those counties. Next, what I want to do afterward is keep certain columns and then have the different years as rows. How should I get around this error?

Per request, here is a small example:

florida is a large list of 8 dataframes. These data frames are the year sheets from the original Excel file. Here is how I worked it for each individual dataframe (using the 2022 dataframe as an example):

```
df2022 <- df2022 %>%
           rename("cocname" = "CoC Name") 
df2022 %>%
  filter(cocname == "Gainesville/Alachua, Putnam Counties CoC")
```

This gives me just the row for the given county. What I'd like to do is write a loop that does this over all dataframes in the list so that each year is a different row.

Comment: you don't use `i` in your loop?

Comment: Wouldn't you know I posted the wrong snip of code? I had two attempts and used the latter by mistake. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use `map2` or `Map` from `base R` - Loop over the `florida` `list`, and the corresponding year '2015' to 2022' in `map2`, `filter` the rows for the specific county in 'cocname' column and where the 'year' (assuming the column name is year) is the looped year

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
out <- map2(florida, 2015:2022, ~ .x %>%
          filter( cocname == "Gainesville/Alachua, Putnam Counties CoC",
               year == .y))
names(out) <- paste0('df', 2015:2022)
list2env(out, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm running into issues with the name of the column. For pulling the column from each individual dataframe, it accepts cocname. If I run something like str(head(df2022)), the dataframe for 2022, the column is listed as $ CoC Name

How can I incorporate that into the filter line of code?

Comment: @theorema.aureum please show a small reproducible example for testing

Comment: I added a small example using the 2022 dataframe.